# Are these php functions correct?

Tags: php, html, forms, function

I just want to know if this piece of code is correct, because for some reason it's not working for me and I don't know why.
If you need me to tell you additional information about my problem or my system just ask for it!

```
<?php
    function add($x,$y) {
        $result= $x+$y;
        return $result;
    };

    $number1= $_POST['n_1'];
    $number2= $_POST['n_2'];
    echo $number1.“ + ".$number2." = ".add($number1,$number2);

    for ($i=5;$i<=50;$i+=5) {
        echo $i."</br>";
    };

    $j=10;
    while ($j>0){
        echo $j.“</br>";
        $j--;
    };
>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action=“thisfile.php" method="POST">
            <label for="fullname">Full name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" size="20"></br>
            <label for="data">Data: </label>
            <textarea rows="5" name="data" cols="20"></textarea></br>
            <label for="valid">Valid?: </label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="valid" value="ON"></br>
            <label for="color">Color: </label>
            <input type="radio" value="blue" checked name="color">Blue
            <input type="radio" value="red" checked name="color">Red</br>
            <label for="month">Month: </label>
            <select size="1" name="month">
                <option selected value="january">January</option> 
                <option value="february">February</option>
                <option value="march">March</option>
            </select></br>
            <label for="n_1">Number 1: </label>
            <input type="text" name="n_1" size="20"></br>
            <label for="n_2">Number 2: </label>
            <input type="text" name="n_2" size="20"></br>
            <input type="submit" value="send" name="send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is no

Comment: Could you explain what's not working more clearly? It looks like you don't close your PHP tag properly (?> instead of >) so that's a start.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` You have several syntax issues, especially curly quotes.

Comment: `“` and `"` are two different things.

Comment: *Curly quotes; beautiful yet deadly!*

Comment: Thanks to all of you that commented! Damn curly quotes! Some parts of the code were copy/pasted from another source and I couldn't notice the curly quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please check the below code, what wrong you did are commented in code:-**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // check all error including warning and notice error too
ini_set('display_errors',1); // display errors
    function add($x,$y) {
        $result= $x+$y;
        return $result;
    } // ; not needed

    $number1= $_POST['n_1'];
    $number2= $_POST['n_2'];
    echo $number1." + ".$number2." = ".add($number1,$number2);// using “ is wrong

    for ($i=5;$i<=50;$i+=5) {
        echo $i."</br>";
    } // ; not needed

    $j=10;
    while ($j>0){
        echo $j."</br>"; // using “ is wrong
        $j--;
    }//; not needed
?> <!-- closing  error-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="thisfile.php" method="POST"> <!--// using “ is wrong -->
            <label for="fullname">Full name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" size="20"></br>
            <label for="data">Data: </label>
            <textarea rows="5" name="data" cols="20"></textarea></br>
            <label for="valid">Valid?: </label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="valid" value="ON"></br>
            <label for="color">Color: </label>
            <input type="radio" value="blue" checked name="color">Blue
            <input type="radio" value="red" checked name="color">Red</br>
            <label for="month">Month: </label>
            <select size="1" name="month">
                <option selected value="january">January</option> 
                <option value="february">February</option>
                <option value="march">March</option>
            </select></br>
            <label for="n_1">Number 1: </label>
            <input type="text" name="n_1" size="20"></br>
            <label for="n_2">Number 2: </label>
            <input type="text" name="n_2" size="20"></br>
            <input type="submit" value="send" name="send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note:- applying `POST` data checks (validation) is your responsibility, add them too along with the code. Thanks**

Comment: Thanks man! Really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

**1. Remove }; make it only }**

And Correct syntax is:

```
<?php

?>
```

you have

```
<?php 

>
```